# How to get the parent of a UserControl hosted in a ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, logical-tree

In a WPF application, I've a `ContentControl`. In this ContentControl, I've a `View`.

Starting from a specific `UserControl`, I'm trying to go up in its logical tree, and "Activate" every component on the way. By example, if one parent is a `Tab`, I select it by example.

My issue is that when my `UserControl` is in a `ContentControl`, when I call the `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(...)` I receive null:

```
    private static void Activate(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        //Here, in one iteration, I receive null when it's supposed to be the `ContentControl`.
        DependencyObject parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(frameworkElement); 
        if (parent is FrameworkElement parentFrameworkElement) 
        {
            Activate(parentFrameworkElement);
        }

        if (frameworkElement is DXTabItem tab)
        {
            tab.IsSelected = true;//If it's a  tab, it gets activated
        }

        frameworkElement.Focus();
    }
```

My Xaml is something like this:

```
<dx:DXTabControl AllowMerging="True" TabContentCacheMode="None" Margin="0,3,0,0">
    <dx:DXTabItem Header="Some channel">
        <local:SomeControl Channel="{Binding Channel}"/>
    </dx:DXTabItem>
    <dx:DXTabItem Header="Some other view">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Channel, Converter={StaticResource SomeModelToViewModelConverter}}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ConventionBasedDataTemplateSelector}" />
    </dx:DXTabItem>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

So: Any idea how to get the `ContentControl` from the control inside it?

**Edit** It seems to be related to the fact that the control is in an unselected tab(the goal of my feature IS to activate the tab in which a usercontrol bound to something is located).

Comment: Why dont you pass the parent object via constructor on child-object creation?

Comment: @Jonas In XAML? Have you ever done that?

Comment: How about VisualTreeHelper?

Comment: @Jonas For a lot of reasons: I bind a model, which is Converted in a ViewModel, for which we have a ContentTemplateSelector, so I never create myself the View, it's the ContentTemplateSelector(which is a ConventionBased converter, that will take the name and remove the "Model" in it.

Comment: @Clemens Ahah; I just tried this now, and same result :'(

Comment: You have to wait until the control is completely loaded. E.g. use a `Loaded` event handler and start traversal from there. And like others have mentioned before use the `VisualTreeHelper` instead.

Comment: @J4N: When and how do you call `Activate`?

Comment: @Clemens What is preventing him from creating an ViewModel for his parent & child. and use Binding for his properties? Maybe I am getting the question wrong, then I am sorry

Comment: @mm8 It's called, guarantee, but it's quite complexe to explain. It comes from a command in a totally different view, which set a a value in a property of a Singleton, on which is bound an usercontrol attached property. When this value change, and that value is equals to a parameter, then it activate the control.

Comment: @BionicCode The Activate is not initiated from the same component, so I'm not aware it's initialized. but I can go on this view, wait 30 seconds, trigger the action, and same result, I don't think it's an initialization issue.

Comment: @Clemens In fact, I was wrong, it kinda works with the VisualTreeHelper, but the issue is that I don't find the parent I was expecting at some point(`DXTabItem`), so I cannot "Select it". Any idea?

Comment: From where do you start the traversal? Are you sure you are starting from a child element in the branch of `DXTabControl `? Maybe you start from a sibling control on the same level?

Comment: You can use the Live Visual Tree window to inspect the tree and verify the real structure. Just start a debug session and then go to _Debug/Windows/Live Visual Tree_

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the elements have been loaded and added to the visual tree, you could use the following recursive method to find the parent element:

```
private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
DXTabItem parent = FindParent<DXTabItem>(frameworkElement);
```

Comment: I tested, it doesn't work, in my case: My control is in a TabControl, in a tab that is not currently displayed(the goal of all this is to display the tab that contains a specific control).

Comment: If the control isn't display, how are you supposed to find in the element tree...? Sorry, this makes no sense.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question!

Comment: @J4N If the tab is not selected (displayed) it is removed from the visual tree.

Comment: @mm8 I've a tab control with 3 tabs, and it's in one of the 2 other tabs, so if you go from parent to child, you can find it. So why would I not find it from child to parent?

Comment: @J4N You should have provided this not quite unimportant information _"the goal of all this is to display the tab that contains a specific control"_ in your question.

Comment: @BionicCode Probably, i didn't think it was relevant at first

Comment: If `FindParent<DXTabItem>` returns `null`, there is no `DXTabItem` parent element in the visual tree.

Comment: @J4N Use the Live Visual Tree Window and see it yourself: the `TabItem` that is not displayed has it's content removed from the visual tree.

Comment: @mm8 my question is not about visual tree, it's about how to get the parent of a ContentControl in not visible tab item.

Comment: @J4N: There is nothing to get a reference to in a not visible tab.

Comment: @J4N You have to trigger on the `Loaded` event which will be raised once the tab is visible.

Comment: @BionicCode Let me explain better: This is used to edit a configuration for some hardware devices. Somewhere totally else, we have a list of error to fix(bit like visual studio), and when I double click, I need to display the exact pane where I can fix this error. The issue is that some "node" that I can edit have several tabs, and I need to display the correct one. But only each of those panes knows what they edit. 

So it means that I've some cases where I will NEVER go into the `Loaded` event before needing to know in which pane this is used.

Comment: @J4N: Instead of trying to explain your issue in the comments field, why don't you update your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) according to the guidelines for how to ask a question on SO?

Comment: @J4N Maybe you are coming from the wrong direction. Each control that contains error data must register itself (report the error). Once registered you can directly access it. This means `DXTabItem` has to register itself as an error source e.g. `ErrorController.RegisterError(control, errorMessage)` then the `ErrorController` can activate the control that maps to the error. If you don't have direct access to the control's internals then create an Attached Behavior to handle this.

Comment: @J4N This is just a quick idea which is not the best. The solution depends on how you structured your UI. How do you display devices? How does `DXTabItem` come into play? But I think you need a new approach. It would be a good idea to update your question to provide more concrete details because your initial approach won't work for your scenario. Then we can find a better solution.